# Robust wireless-able joycons

Tags: controllers, nintendo-switch

I have two pairs of official Joycons from Nintendo, but both have their directional sticks drifting. 
As recommended in several places, I tried to clean them, and to re-calibrate them via the Switch menu, but it does not help.

I think this must be a consistent problem with Nintendo-made joycons, and am looking for alternative joycon controllers that will not have this problem, even after extensive usage (by gamers of various age).

I read about Hori controllers but understood that they cannot be used separated from the console.

What alternative joycons can I get, that will not suffer from stick-drift after a few months ; and that can also be used wirelessly?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up using this [Nintendo Switch Joycons Control Sticks Repair Kit](https://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/B07NVQMLCK) because it had a lot of positive reviews.

I followed the tutorial https://www.imore.com/how-replace-joystick-your-switch-joy-cons to replace the stick that was drifting in my Joycon ; it now works as good as when it was new (I checked in the Stick Calibration menu that there was no drift at all).

I will update my answer if it turns out using this replacement stick is not a good long-term solution.